# When to generate Registration ID in Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am working with android app in which i am using GCM. now I don't know when to create new Registration Id for device.?
I am saving Registration Id in sharedpreferences.
and i know that when app version changes we have to regenerate ID.
but when user logout from app, does it necessary to regenerate ID ?
Can I use previous Reg Id for that particular user because I am storing it in database.
can multiple devices have same Registration IDs?

Comment: What do you mean by `logout from app`?

Comment: clearing sharedpreference. if i clear sharedpreference,and when user login again then do i need to regenerate RegID or i can use user's old ID which is stored in my database ?

Comment: It depends on your implementation. On the app, how do you determine that the user's registration ID has already been sent to your server's database?

Comment: i will use email id and password , if user's RegId is there in database (my server's database) i will simply return it.

Comment: I can see that you have already gotten help. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the device ID on following cases.

1. Lgout/Login(in case of multiple users)
2. App version change.
3. OS updates.

Answer (score 1):

You should regenerate the registration id on phone reboots, app updates and OS updates. Check this [blog post](https://blog.pushbullet.com/2014/02/12/keeping-google-cloud-messaging-for-android-working-reliably-techincal-post/).

Answer (score 0):

Hope I'm not intruding on what @iRuth is planning to advise. Here are some things I want to point out:

1. One registration ID per device is sufficient.

   - If different users can log in from the same device, you could modify the `data` field in your message to specify the intended user/recipient. Multiple devices cannot have the same registration IDs.
2. Do not regenerate registration ID after every log out.

   - Persist the registration ID on the client device. Like you said, only app updates and backups merit another `gcm.register()` call.

Lastly, I am assuming that by database you meant the client device's database. In that case, yes, just use the already existing registration ID. If you meant your server's database, you will always need to maintain a record on your device of the registration ID and its associated app version. Only having it on your server's DB is not advisable as your client device may no longer be reachable via GCM if the app has been updated.

Comment: I m using server's database. so there will be a mapping from userid to RegId,when user login i will check if this user has already registered or not if yes i will fetch RegId from database and send it to client's device. is this implementation is correct ? cant i regenerate RegID whenever user login ?

Comment: I think you should sync the registration id from mobile app side to the server database side. So on starting the first activity of your app, check if your registration id exists in your shared preferences. If it does not exist, register the new registration id from GCM in a background job, store it in shared preferences and also send to server db. if it exists in shared preferences, you can happily proceed. Please see the instructions here:

https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

Comment: thank you Tony. i am doing similar thing. but my question is suppose user has cleared data of App. and its RegID is stored in my server database.so when user starts App,in shared preference there will be no registration id,now can i assign that RegId which is there on My Server ?? i will distinguish RegId by Usernames which are Unique.